# dialog box displays only the last item in the array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to display data from a an array list but after the marker onclick
it only displays the last element in the array list in the material dialog box
 DriverLocationDataManager gets all the data snapshots of the geopoints of the drivers in the database

after adding in all the driver data, i use the addMarker function which gets the geopoints and set the markers on the map.

```
//Init data manager

    drivers = new ArrayList<>(0);



    dataManager = new DriverLocationDataManager(this) {
        @Override
        public void onDataLoaded(List<Driver> data) {
            if (data.isEmpty()) {
                Snackbar.make(container, "Sorry!. UG Shuttle service is currently unavailable",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
            } else {

                drivers.addAll(data);


                List<Marker> markers = addMarkers(data);
                for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++){
                    markers.get(i);
                    Driver driver = drivers.get(i);
                    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
                        // Get custom view
                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.driver_popup, null, false);

                        //Assign props
                        TextView username = v.findViewById(R.id.driver_username);
                        CircularImageView profile = v.findViewById(R.id.driver_profile);
                        ImageView status = v.findViewById(R.id.driver_status);
                        TextView shuttle = v.findViewById(R.id.driver_bus_number);
                        ViewGroup viewGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.group);

                        //Init props
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(driver.getProfile())
                                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder))
                                .apply(RequestOptions.errorOf(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder))
                                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC))
                                .transition(withCrossFade())
                                .into(profile);

                        username.setText(driver.getDriver());   //Driver's username
                        shuttle.setText(driver.getCarNumber()); //Driver's car number

                        //Attach to dialog
                        Builder materialDialog = new Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                                .customView(v, true)
                                .negativeText("Dismiss")
                                .onPositive((dialog, which) -> {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    enableTracking(marker);
                                })
                                .onNegative((dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

                        if (driver.isStatus()) {
                            status.setImageResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);  //Online

                            //Enable tracking when driver is online
                            materialDialog.positiveText("Track")
                                    .onPositive((dialog, which) -> {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        enableTracking(marker);
                                    });
                        } else {
                            //Tracking is disabled
                            status.setImageResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light);    //Offline
                        }

                        materialDialog.build().show();
                        return true;
                    });



                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You have build `Dialog` inside for loop . Build it outside loop when data is processed .

Comment: that doesnt help since i want all the instance of the driver objects

Comment: i dont want to show multiple dialogboxes, each marker click shows one dialog box inflated by the data from the driver object,

Comment: i dont want to show multiple dialogboxes, each marker click shows one dialog box inflated by the data from the driver object,

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read the official developer guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs). It explains how to properly use Dialogs, how to display a list in it, and even how to implement a custom view if you need one to display your list.